# How to Insert a Space Between Bullet Points and a Markdown Heading in ReactMarkdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown, react-markdown

I'm working with ReactMarkdown to render markdown content in a React application, and I've encountered an issue where I can't seem to insert a space between the last bullet point in a list and a subsequent markdown heading. I've tried using backslashes and HTML comments to achieve this separation, but ReactMarkdown doesn't seem to respect these methods. Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
- **Example**: Text
\
#### Achieving Cloud Efficiency
```

### And with an HTML comment:

```
- **Example**: Text
<!-- -->
#### Achieving Cloud Efficiency
```

Neither of these approaches worked when rendered using ReactMarkdown:

```
<ReactMarkdown>{values.markdownBody}</ReactMarkdown>
```

I'm looking for a way to ensure there's a visual space or separation between the last item of the bullet list and the heading that follows. What is the correct way to achieve this spacing in ReactMarkdown?